# Can we have $N\oplus P=N' \oplus P$ for $N' \subsetneq N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

> Let $M$ be a $R$-module. Is it possible that we have two submodules $N,P \subset M$ such that $M=N\oplus P$ and also $M=N'\oplus P$ for some $N' \subsetneq N$?

If $R$ is a field and $M$ a finite dimensional $R$-vectorspace then this obviously can't happen because of dimension reasons. But if there aren't any constraints on $R$, is this still impossible?

Comment: Using the 2nd decomposition $n = n' + p$, uniquely.
However, using the first decomposition, $p=0$ (because $n-n' = p$). Hence $n = n'$.

Comment: You could get an $R$-module isomorphism...

Comment: Note that any dimension-counting arguments are only valid in the finite-dimensional case.

Comment: oh yes you are right. @peter a g : i don't really understand what you mean, could you be a bit more detailed?

Comment: As you see @D_S explained...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say $M = N \oplus P$, what you are saying is two things: first, that $N \cap P = \{0\}$, and second, that every $m \in M$ can be expressed as $n + p$ for some $n \in N$ and $p \in P$.

Now suppose $N' \subsetneq N$, with $M = N \oplus P$ and $M = N' \oplus P$.  Let $n \in N$.  Then there exist $n' \in N'$, and $p \in P$, such that $n = n' + p$.  It follows that $n - n' = p \in N \cap P = \{0\}$, and so $n = n'$.  In particular, every element of $N$ lies in $N'$, contradiction.

Comment: On the other hand, you can certainly have that $N' + P$ is isomorphic to $N + P$, even if $N' \subsetneq N$.